# Cant find facebook post id using js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hey guys i have been trying to fetch the post id from the response. My code is

```
function testAPI() {


 var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {

  if (!response || response.error) {

  } else {

console.log(response);

}

)};

}
```

When i check the console i didnt find the details of message object..Is it a bug ??What i need is to print the message id and the message on the console .Can i do this with facebook js-sdk ?..If am doing any wrong please help me to do this rightly ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code - it looks like there's a syntax error. You need to remove the second to last `}`.

Removing that and re-formatting the code will enable you to get the id successfully - I just tried it. The fixed code is below:

```
function testAPI() {

var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';

  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
    } else {
      console.log(response); // 
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: did you get the message id ??

Comment: .i still didnt get it ..it would be helpful if you post the correct code as answer ..i would accept the answer

Comment: i get the user id but i didnt get the message id ??

Comment: .but it didnt give me the output "Reading JS SDK documentation" on the console ..is this can be done with fb js sdk

Comment: It gives you the id of the post you just published. You can visit the post at facebook.com/{idhere} or query it using `FB.api` to get the full details. Why do you want the message?

Comment: when i tried ur code it didnt gives me message id but it gives an object with auth response object ...

Comment: Please paste the contents of the authResponse object. I'm 95% sure that means the user isn't logged in or hasn't provided the permissions.

Comment: ..oops am sorry the app didnt has the permission for accessing feeds ..:D

Comment: can we code like /'me'/feed?message=body', ..so that we can avoid the params ??

Comment: ...can we code like /'me'/feed?message=body', ..so that we can avoid the params ?? –

Comment: Don't think so, this is a POST request, it's different to GET.

Comment: thanks ..can i pass an object without a "post". if i add { message: "something"} to the code without "post" ..is there any error ??